# non parallelizable loop in jomp and openmp

Tags: java, loops, parallel-processing, openmp

i have a next loop

```
for(int i=1;i<n;i++){
a[i]=(a[i]+a[i-1])/2;
}
```

obviously that this loop isn't parallelizable
because the result of each element depends on the element that before it
anyway
i tried to parallelize it with JOMP (openmp)

```
//omp parallel shared(a)
{
//omp for 
for(int i=1;i<n;i++){
a[i]=(a[i]+a[i-1])/2;
}}}
```

and it give me a right result (which make me crazy)
why it's giving me the same result as the series code
can anyone give me a logical explanation

Comment: Does JOMP always parallelize? Does it fallback to a non-parallelized solution when parallelization is not possible?

Comment: i googled but didn't find the answers for these questions